# Devise how to add a addtional field to the create User form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to add a username to my User on create.

In devise/registrations/new I have:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

The problem is there is no `params[:username]` sent to the controller and I get the following error in the view:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Mysql::Error: Column 'username' cannot be null:
  INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `encrypted_password`, `reset_password_token`,
  `reset_password_sent_at`, `remember_created_at`, `sign_in_count`,
  `current_sign_in_at`, `last_sign_in_at`, `current_sign_in_ip`, `last_sign_in_ip`,
  `created_at`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES ('mail@test.dk',
  '$2a$10$bWjAXLY8QGXrXeVrGciv2O6mjRF940lajBEsUOPPtPDhKyj0A/gia', NULL, NULL,
  NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-05-15 16:16:36', '2011-05-15 16:16:36',
  NULL)

Rails.root: C:/Rails/densjove
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qkQ8L0ZonXYxWQ2f4cfdREZ222oa2zGUb/qll3TRxjQ=",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"hansen",
 "email"=>"mail@test.dk",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I have added the `username` coloumn to my model, but how can I access the `params[:username]` in my controller?

Comment: Why is the username not submitted ?

Comment: Problem solved I did foreget to add the username params to the attr_accessible

Comment: Full answer here : [Add custom fields to Devise user model](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/)

Comment: you should add your second comment as an answer, and mark it as the correct one. That way, future visitors to this question can know it's the right answer, and not have to look through comments.

Answer (score 13):

Rails 4 moved the param sanitizing to the controller.

One way to add custom fields for devise is to add a before filter in the Application Controller calling a method to define which are your permitted parameters.

In Code From https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

The above code is if you are adding a field named username. If you were adding first_name it would be:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
```

This is one way and I strongly consider reading over the docs at the link above in order to learn more about customizing devise to permit certain fields.

Answer (score 1):

Add the username field to attr_accessible in app/model/user.rb

```
# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
```

Taken from comment #1 above so others can easily see the solution

Comment: attr_accessible is not valid on rails4. Any ideas on how it should be done there?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 Strong Params way to add to the controller

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: -1: link answers are bad, because links easily become broken.

Comment: You must explain what are the steps you use to have it working well!

Answer (score 0):

If you are wishing to add FirstName, LastName or any column while Registration of User, You have to configure those column with devise permitted parameters.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_new_column_to_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_new_column_to_devise_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]
    if params[:action] == 'create'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
      }
    elsif params[:action] == 'update'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
      }
    end
  end    
end
```

For example : To add one more column like alternate_email at User Registration, Just add alternate_email column to registration_params

> registration_params = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password,
>   :password_confirmation, :alternate_email ]

email]