# Local works, on Heroku ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I use Rails 4 and Devise gem for authorization.
I add additional field to registration form for Device called 'username'
It's here:

```
enter code here
<div><%= f.label :username %><br />
<%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %></div>
```

I done it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667360/3826643

Local it works fine. I can sign up and in my user panel I can see user name typed in sugn up form.

On heroku when i click 'Sign up" i give "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Heroku logs here:

```
2014-07-11T10:02:24.514630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_up" host=test-app12.herokuapp.com request_id=32d968fd-2154-4a02-ba8a-878bb7f85a02 fwd="78.8.153.110" dyno=web.1 connect=5 service=378 status=500 bytes=857
2014-07-11T10:02:24.509598+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (73.9ms)
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515127+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515132+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username' for #<User:0x007f2b303b0378>):
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515134+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:   <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515136+00:00 app[web.1]:      9: 
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515138+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515140+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %></div>
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515142+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: 
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515145+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:   <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515147+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:     <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515150+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:11:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__2151626084088518473_69911734787000'
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515152+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__2151626084088518473_69911734787000'
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515154+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-11T10:02:24.515156+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-11T10:02:24.510327+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 195ms
```

I haven't done any db migration and stuff like that.

For me it's a little wired that everything is OK local but on Heroku it gives action view error.

Of course before I push from git new views and controllers with additional field 'username' it worked fine on Heroku.

Comment: If i remove from new.html.erb lines for user field, I mean: `<div><%= f.label :username %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %></div>` It works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `heroku run rake db:migrate` so when the app boots the ActiveRecord initialisation picks up the attributes of the model and is available to the form helpers.

Comment: Thanks but I've just tried `heroku run rake db:migrate` and after it `heroku restert` but problem is the same

Comment: And I have changed controllers, not models - changes only in application_cotnroller. Like in link I paste above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was issue with database on heroku. Column username in table was missing because migration file was lost and I didn't notice it. Thanks @John Beynon for suggestion the problem is with database